# IntelliSense в VS Code для JavaScript не все события показывает

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, intellisense

IntelliSense в VS Code для JavaScript не все события показывает. Пример кода.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="a">Hello World!</div>
</body>
 <script>
  let a = document.querySelector(".a");
  a.onclick = function () {
   a.style.color = "#ff0000";
  }
 </script>
</html>
```

После переменной **a** я ставлю точку, ввожу букву **o**, по идее, должнен появитсья весь список событий, где я могу выбрать **onclick**, так происходит в IntelliJ IDEA, но в VS Code появляется пару событий, где нет **onclick**. Нет свойства **style**. Но если я просто ввожу **on**, то список появляется.  Подскажите, что нужно сделать, какой плагин подключить, сейчас все из коробки.

Comment: Думаю это сделано намеренно. В DOM Level-2 изменилась модель событий и подобным образом редактор просит использовать более новые стандарты. `addEventListener('click', callback)` будет дополнять.

Comment: Уважаемый Roman Stoliarenko! Спасибо Вам!  addEventListener() появляется, но style не появляется в событии. А вот document.querySelector(".text").style - появляется.

Comment: В принципе современный веб пишется на библиотеках и фреймворках. Это JS, тут библиотеки которые с помощью библиотек делают библиотеки для фреймворков))) Скоро сниппеты будут писать каркас файла, который нужно будет наполнить логикой из сниппетов, в которые нужно вписать свой код. Не забивайте голову автодополнениями. Ctrl + spase покажет что есть, если нет - пишите. Кажется это ценно, знать как писать быстро без автодополнений)